# Array doesn't keep it's value outside of the method it's filled in

Tags: c#

I have this line of code that gets the ids of a table and feeds them to an int array, called idPuntos (Note: This method is sandwiched between the Open() and Close() methods somewhere else, so it's not something about the database in that sense).

```
    public void refreshIds()
        {
        idInit.Clear();
        try
            {
            SqlCommand getIds = new SqlCommand("SELECT id_punto FROM Puntos", cnn);
            SqlDataReader idsReader = getIds.ExecuteReader();
            while (idsReader.Read())
                {
                //idInit is a global ArrayList
                idInit.Add(idsReader[0]);

                }
            //idPuntos is a global array, declared without value
            idPuntos = (int[])idInit.ToArray(typeof(int));
            //This line works here, I test printed it and got the values I wanted, yet it doesn't work in the following method...
            bajaId = idPuntos[0];

            }
        catch (SqlException)
            {
            statusbajas.Text = "Hubo un error al recuperar los datos.";
            }

        }
```

It won't work here:

```
    private void listabajas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //it doesnt work here, and i dont understand why
        bajaId = idPuntos[0];
        //statusbajas.Text = "es " + listabajas.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        }
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: By not working, I mean idPuntos[0] appears to be null while it isn't in the first, where it actually holds the value I feed it.

EDIT 2: The problem seems to start since the constructor. Putting a breakpoint on the first Close() call, made me realize the crash occurs since that point.

This is my constructor:

```
    public AltasPuntos()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        str = Properties.Settings.Default.SWMConnString;
        cnn = new SqlConnection(str);
        cnn.Open();
        refreshListNombres();
        cnn.Close();
        cnn.Open();
        refreshIds();
        cnn.Close();   
        }
```

Comment: Explain what "doesn't work" mean exactly.

Comment: Sorry, in the second method, idPuntos[0] appears to be null, while in the first it does hold the value I feed it.

Comment: You are calling `listabajas_SelectedIndexChanged()` before array initialization or array is located in the other instance. Put the breakpoint on the `bajaId = idPuntos[0];` line and check if your `idPuntos` has been initialized.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET WebForms application?

Comment: It's a WindowsFormsApplication, .NET Framework 4.5 using C#.

Btw, all variables are global. Can listabajas_SelectedIndexChanged() be called before array initialization? I run the refreshIds() method at the form load (at the start), not sure if listabajas_SelectedIndexChanged() is called by default for being a Design item.

Comment: What is null? idPunto or idPunto[0]? You could improve your query "SELECT id_punto FROM Puntos WHERE id_punto IS NOT NULL"

Comment: id_punto is Primary Key so it shouldn't have null values. I'll still try this.
Edit: the IDE says idPunto is null.

Comment: Same result. Other answer helped me see that listabajas_SelectedIndexChanged() is called first so there's the problem or at least it keeps sending me there no matter how early I call refreshIds. Now, how to call it after refreshIds is the problem, I already put refreshIds at the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that `refreshIds` is called before `listabajas_SelectedIndexChanged` gets fired.

If you're using WinForms, you can put a call to `refreshIds` into the constructor the the form.

That's about as much as I can suggest from the information provided in the question.

Comment: I moved the call to the constructor but it still says the value is null in the IndexChanged method.

Comment: Do you have calls to `refreshIds` anywhere else? `idPunto[0]` could become null if it's called with a query that returns nothing. Can you put a breakpoint on `bajaId = idPuntos[0]` in `refreshIds` and see when it's hit?

Comment: I put the breakpoint, and it definetely calls listabajas_SelectedIndexChanged first, because it stopped before the breakpoint. I should just find a way to call refreshIds first, I guess?

Comment: `listabajas_SelectedIndexChanged` cannot be called before the constructor of the form. This is impossible. You can put breakpoints in the constructor, and follow it through to see the execution order.

Comment: I put a breakpoint in the constructor where I call refreshIds, it still sends me to listabajas_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: Actually, the error starts since the first Close().

I'll add the constructor to the question.

Comment: I'll try adding a Select button so it doesn't try using idPuntos before refreshIds is called.